# Reading .txt file as list and writing list to 'single excel cell' using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, list, openpyxl

I am reading data from a multi-line '.txt' file and converting it to a list while reading, and trying to write the list to a 'single cell' of excel sheet using the following code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

with open('Wavedata.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
print(lines)

wb = load_workbook("Wavesheet.xlsx")
sheet = wb["Sheet1"]
sheet['A1'] = lines

wb.save("Wavesheet.xlsx")
```

The list is generated successfully as:
['123.23', '145.43', '156.29', '145.16', '150.23', '154.21', '155.31', '155.29', '155.64', '155.32', '154.69', '151.65', '150.89', '146.87', '145.52', '124.32']

but `sheet['A1'] = lines` part of the code doesn't work and the error generated:

```
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 205, in _bind_value
    raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))

ValueError: Cannot convert ['123.23', '145.43', '156.29', '145.16', '150.23', '154.21', '155.31', '155.29', '155.64', '155.32', '154.69', '151.65', '150.89', '146.87', '145.52', '124.32'] to Excel
```

Can anyone suggest how can I write the list to a 'single cell' of the Excel sheet including '[' at the start and ']' at the end of the list?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert your list to a string.

```
outputlist = ['123.23', '145.43', '156.29', '145.16', '150.23', '154.21', '155.31', '155.29', '155.64', '155.32', '154.69', '151.65', '150.89', '146.87', '145.52', '124.32']
outputstring ="['" +  '\', \''.join(outputlist) + "']"
print(outputlist, type(outputlist))
print(outputstring, type(outputstring))
```

Output:

```
['123.23', '145.43', '156.29', '145.16', '150.23', '154.21', '155.31', '155.29', '155.64', '155.32', '154.69', '151.65', '150.89', '146.87', '145.52', '124.32'] <class 'list'>
['123.23', '145.43', '156.29', '145.16', '150.23', '154.21', '155.31', '155.29', '155.64', '155.32', '154.69', '151.65', '150.89', '146.87', '145.52', '124.32'] <class 'str'>
```